# Android No view found for id

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I am just starting with android development in Eclipse and am following the developer tutorials. When experimenting with fragments i bumped into this error in Logcat "No view found for id ...." i tried looking through several similar posts about this error but somehow the solutions don't work for me (or i am missing the point). Anyway this is my situation. I have got one activity and two fragments which i dynamically want to show. The problem is that when i replace the first fragment with the second one and THEN hit the back button i get this error. Here is the relevant code:

OnCreate of my main activity (named MainAcitity2):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        myFirstFragment firstFragment = new myFirstFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }        
}
```

This is the layout of my main acitity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp2.MainActivity2" >
```

in myFirstFragment i used the code to communicate between Fragments, namely by specifying and interface which is implemented in my main acitivy and which in my case creates the seconde Fragments and passes some string text. Her is the implementation of this interface in my main activity:

```
    public void OnMyButtonClicked(String thetext){

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("THETEXT", thetext);

    mySecondFragment newFragment = new mySecondFragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();       

}
```

This is the onCreateView code for mySecondFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String message = "NIET ONTVANGEN";

    message=this.getArguments().getString("THETEXT");           
    System.out.println("DE MESSAGE NA OVERDRACHT IS:"+message);

    //create the TextView
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    getActivity().setContentView(textView);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_second_fragment,container, false);

    return view;
}
```

So far everything works fine. The first fragment is shown first. Then when i click the button and invoke the implemented interface the second fragment is shown and replaces the first one (and shows me some text i passed through), but when i click the back button the error is given. Below is some more possibly relevant code

Layout xml of myFirstFragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/firstfragment_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_message" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/audio_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_play"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_input" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of mySecondFragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/secondfragment_view"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp2.DisplayMessageActivity" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/myLargeImage"      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the output of LogCat as:

```
   10-14 14:47:35.936: E/FragmentManager(26088): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp2:id/fragment_container) for fragment myFirstFragment{42a4bb70 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-14 14:47:35.936: E/FragmentManager(26088): Activity state:
10-14 14:47:35.946: E/InputEventSender(26088): Exception dispatching finished signal.
10-14 14:47:35.946: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp2:id/fragment_container) for fragment myFirstFragment{42a4bb70 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1533)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:498)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:180)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onBackPressed(ActionBarActivity.java:251)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2295)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3197)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2529)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:258)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2165)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4635)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4602)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4301)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4334)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4494)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2267)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1915)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1906)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2244)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/MessageQueue-JNI(26088):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088): Process: com.example.myfirstapp2, PID: 26088
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp2:id/fragment_container) for fragment myFirstFragment{42a4bb70 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1533)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:498)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:180)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onBackPressed(ActionBarActivity.java:251)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2295)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3197)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2529)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:258)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2165)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4635)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4602)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4301)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4334)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4494)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2267)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1915)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1906)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2244)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-14 14:47:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26088):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: please post your Logcat output of Error

Comment: *getActivity().setContentView(textView);*?\

Comment: Perhaps it is obvious but what is wrong with that statement?

Comment: Anybody got another answer for this?